# Handlebars or ember blocking href to external url

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I'm using ember.js with handlebars, and it seems external URL cannot be reached without a script. I put a link to www.google.com to test and it never fires! Is there something I am missing on?

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="subusers">  
    <div class="click-nav" {{action 'toggleDdSubusers'}}>
        <ul class="no-js" >
            <li>
                <a class="clicker">
                    {{render 'currentsubuser'}}
                </a>
                 <ul class="filter-options">
                    {{#each subuser in model}}
                        {{#unless (equals subuser.id currentSubuserInfos.id)}}                                 
                            <li>
                                <a href="http://www.google.com">
                                    <span class="profileimg">{{{subuser.profileImage}}}</span>{{subuser.name}}<span class="numbers"> ({{subuser.openedConvCount}})</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        {{/unless}}
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle to demonstrate your problem ? A simple link is working fine for me on a clean new project.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why I got this behavior on my app. What I did to solve my problem is I put an action on my li and send the wanted redirect URL as a function parameter.

In this action, I simply manually redirect with : window.location.href = paramUrl.